# error: Uncaught (in promise) AssertionError

Tags: mongodb, assertion, deno, uncaught-exception

I am a new Deno learner, I tried a tutorial code that uses MongoDB but I got the following error:

```
error: Uncaught (in promise) AssertionError
    throw new AssertionError(msg);
          ^
    at assert (https://deno.land/std@0.107.0/testing/asserts.ts:224:11)
    at MongoClient.database (https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.27.0/src/client.ts:67:5)
    at file:///C:/Users/m/Desktop/Uproject/GuidApp/deno-survey/mongo.ts:6:19
```

As the project has many files, Let me know if is it needed to add some parts of project codes here?
But the whole project code can be find here: https://github.com/thecodeholic/deno-survey

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in the `mongo.ts` file of the project, there is a line like this:

```
client.connect(Deno.env.get("MONGODB_URI") || "");
```

That I must add the `await` keyword in front of it and change it like below:

```
await client.connect(Deno.env.get("MONGODB_URI") || "");
```

Problem resolved by this.